# ActiveAdmin with Rails 5 API mode

Tags: ruby, api, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I'm trying to get activeadmin working with Rails 5 API mode. There's several [articles](https://medium.com/superhighfives/a-top-shelf-web-stack-rails-5-api-activeadmin-create-react-app-de5481b7ec0b) about this, and they pretty much all say the same thing.

First, make the application controller extend from `ActionController::Base` instead of `ActionController::API`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
end
```

Then create an ApiController, which every other controller extends from:

```
class ApiController < ActionController::API

end
```

Add middelware:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::MethodOverride
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
```

Then add gems (I'm using devise_token_auth instead of devise)

```
gem 'devise', '> 4.x'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'inherited_resources', git: 'https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources'
```

And run `bin/rails g active_admin:install`. This is where it all goes wrong:

```
      invoke    active_record
      create      db/migrate/20170821114552_devise_create_admin_users.rb
      create      app/models/admin_user.rb
      invoke      rspec
      create        spec/models/admin_user_spec.rb
      invoke        factory_girl
      create          spec/factories/admin_users.rb
      insert      app/models/admin_user.rb
       route    devise_for :admin_users
        gsub    app/models/admin_user.rb
        gsub    config/routes.rb
      append    db/seeds.rb
      create  config/initializers/active_admin.rb
       exist  app/admin
      create  app/admin/dashboard.rb
      create  app/admin/admin_user.rb
      insert  config/routes.rb
    generate  active_admin:assets
/home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `assets' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000003fc9740>
Did you mean?  asset_host (NoMethodError)
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/engine.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/engine.rb:4:in `each'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/engine.rb:4:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
        from /home/blop/Development/railsapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:102:in `preload'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /home/blop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
      create  db/migrate/20170821114605_create_active_admin_comments.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use Rails API if you really need full Rails? Rails API was designed to get rid off the unnecessary staff, such as views, cookies, sessions, etc. All that staff is mandatory for ActiveAdmin. You don't get any benefits from using Rails API in such configuration.

So, for me there are two options:

1. Don't use Rails API.
2. Create two separate applications (API and Admin) with two different Gemfiles and shared models. In wake of convenience you can store both apps in the same repository.

Comment: ActiveAdmin is a temporary solution I want to get rid of in the near future